# Is $A \subset \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}}$ if every element in $A$ is orthogonal to each $f_n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $H$. Further, let $A \subset H$ be a closed subspace of $H$. Suppose that the following property holds:

For every $a \in A$ the implication
$$
\langle f_n,a \rangle = 0 \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies a=0
$$
holds true. Can we conclude that $A \subset \overline{\mathrm{span} \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}}$, i.e. $A$ is a subspace of the closure of the linear span of all $f_n$'s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cant conclude that $A\subseteq \overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$. For example take $H=\mathbb{R^3}$ with the Euclidean norm $||.||_2$. Take $f_1=(1,0,0)$ and $f_n=f_1$ for every $n$. For $A$ take $\text{span}\bigl((1,1,0)\bigr)$. Then,
$$\overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}=\{(\lambda,0,0)\,:\, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
and if  $(\mu,\mu,0)\cdot (1,0,0)=0$ then $\mu=0$. So the only vector of $A$ which is vertical to $\overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$ is the zero element. But of course $A\subsetneq \overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$. You can also construct an example where the sequence is non constant.

For example if $H=\ell_2$ with $||x||_2=\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k|^2\biggr)^{1/2}$ where $x=(x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$. Then, take $f_n=e_{n+1}$ where $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is the standard basis of $\ell_2$. Let $A=\text{span}(e_1+e_2)=\{x\in \ell_2:\, x=(\lambda,\lambda,0,0,...),\, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then, you can check again that the only element which is perpendicular to $\overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$ is the zero element. But, $A\subsetneq \overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$ since
$$\overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}=\{x\in \ell_2:\,x=(0,x_1,x_2,...),\, x_n\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
and $(1,1,0,0,0,...)$ belongs to $A$ but not to $\overline{\text{span}\{f_n\,:\,n\in \mathbb{N}\}}$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!